# Shallow copy 2 ArrayList into 1 in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, shallow-copy

```
ArrayList<String> myString = new ArrayList<String>();
myString.add("string_1");
myString.add("string_2");

ArrayList<String> yourString = new ArrayList<String>();
yourString.add("string_11");
yourString.add("string_12");

ArrayList<String> string1 = myString;
ArrayList<String> string2 = yourString;
```

This will shallow copy `myString` to `string1` and `yourString` to `string2`.

So, if I do

```
myString.add("string_3");
```

`string1.size()` will give me `3`

How can I shallow copy both `myString` and `yourString` into an ArrayList say `string3` (e.g. `ArrayList<String> string3 = myString + yourString`)?

Comment: Is it even possible? You can not reference two different objects with one reference

Comment: Why you need to have that reference?

Comment: @Tony : I want to skip the pain of deep copy the list every time I update my ListView.

Comment: @YassinHajaj : I understand that. Any way around here? I want to skip the pain of deep copy the list every time I update my ListView.

Comment: @Hemanth I don't think you have a choice here... :s

Comment: Instead, I think you can use an ArrayList of ArrayList like this: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen great idea. will give it a try.

Comment: or you can use Hashmap with the value is array list and configure your list view adapter to work with that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you maintain three lists, myString, yourString and ourString.

```
List<String> ourString = new ArrayList<String>();
ourString.addAll(myString);
ourString.addAll(yourString);
```

Now, your string3 array can be refer to this third list. Now, whenever you update either myString or yourString, you can update ourString accordingly (basically, performing two add operations instead of one, which is still O(1), as compared to O(n) while performing a deep copy). This will also update string3 as you want.

Comment: What if I do `myString.add("string_3");` and then `System.out.println(string3);` It will still print `[string_1, string_2, string_11, string_12]`

Comment: that is what I said, you have to perform 'two' add operations everytime. Whenever you add to myString or yourString, you have to add to ourString as well. This will be asymptotically faster than performing a deep copy everytime.

Comment: got that. Instead I would got ahead with ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. Its more faster than your approach. what you think?

Comment: If you keep string3 as a nested arraylist, you will have to construct the full arraylist everytime you wish to perform some operation on string3 (assuming you keep references to myString and yourString in the nested arraylist). So it will essentially be a O(n) operation (assuming both arrays are equally split. If one of the arrays is very small always, say with 1 or 2 elements, then this will be as fast as what I suggested)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

This method will help you!

```
public static ArrayList<String> cloneList(ArrayList<String> yourList) {
ArrayList<List> clonedList = new ArrayList<String>(yourList.size());
for (String s : yourList) {
    clonedList.add(new String(""));
}
return clonedList;
}
```

here is some code: `ArrayList<String> shallow = new ArrayList(yourOriginalList);`

Comment: What if I do `myString.add("string_3");` and then `System.out.println(string3);` It will still print `[string_1, string_2, string_11, string_12]`

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is to go the hard way and write a ConcatList and implement the List-Interface:

```
   public class ConcatList<E> implements List<E> {

    private List<E> head;

    private List<E> tail;


    public ConcatList(List<E> head, List<E> tail) {
        super();
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return head.size() + tail.size();
    }

...
```

Its no ArrayList, but it could be that what you want.